# `transform` function across DDP connections

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, ddp

I am using `dburles:collection-helpers`. I noticed that, when I create a collection via DDP connection, it causes a few problems.

```
connection = DDP.connect('someurl');
Meteor.users = new Mongo.Collection('users', connection);
```

Now, any instance of `Meteor.users` on this application does not have the helpers defined in my main application. It is also not of type `Document`, implying collection-helpers isn't working.

Taking a quick glance at the source of collection helpers, it looks like it just takes the map of helpers and applies it as a transform function.

Do transform functions not travel across DDP connections? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: DDP transmits serialized JSON sobjects. Functions are not serialized, therefore helper functions will not be applied. You'd need to have the transform be defined on the connected client.

Comment: Sounds like that's the answer.